# PHP - SQL query is not returning any results

Tags: php

I must be missing something very obvious here, but I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. For some reason, $row is coming out empty, which should not happen. I am getting no error though.

```
$uname=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION["username"]);
$query1="SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username='$uname'";

$results=$conn->query($query1);
if($results->num_rows>0){
    while($row=$results->fetch_assoc()){
        $uid=mysqli_real_escape_string($row["user_id"]);
    }
}
```

I am sorry if this is a bad question, I will delete it right after, but I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You're not actually checking for [errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), so how do you know?

Comment: echo your query try to run in PHPMyAdmin. is it returning some data?

Comment: I would try `$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result)`

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). And you'll never have to worry about pesky quoting issues again.

Comment: Actually, no error is being displayed in the log, so I thought I might not have errors. I am still learning. Thank you for the links you provided. @aynber

Comment: The query is returning results in PHPmyadmin @MuhammadUsman

Comment: Is using mysqli_num_rows() better? @MaxZoom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No question is a bad question imo..we are all here to learn isnt it?I'd rather construct that code this way:

```
$uname=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION["username"]);
$query1=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username='$uname'");

if ($query1){
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1){
      $user_id = $row['user_id'];
      echo $user_id;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is working. I did not know we could do it like this. Thank you! I need to read up more.

Comment: And about the bad question thing, it happened to me once before, it was a question like this and I had to delete it without ever getting an answer.

Comment: It happened to me too severally, but the key is never to get deterred.

Comment: I try not to. Btw, I did understand what you did, but could you tell me what I was doing wrong?

Comment: This line `$uid=mysqli_real_escape_string($row["user_id"]);` was unneccessary. I guess it broke ur code. Try with `$uid = ($row['user_id']);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    $uname=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION["username"]);
$query1="SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username=
'$uname'";

$results=mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
if(mysqli_num_rows($results) >0){
    $row=$results->fetch_assoc();
    $uid=$row["user_id"];
}
```

Comment: Bad concatenation there. You don't need the periods.

Comment: Echo ur query and check

Comment: @aynber try it now.

Comment: I tried this, but this is not working for some reason. Can you please explain what you have done?